# Why TypeTag doesnt have method runtimeClass but Manifest and ClassTag do

Tags: scala

I have this code to generically transform String to Dto, if I am using Manifest and ClassTag, both of it I can use method **runtimeClass** to get runtime class, but TypeTag doesnt have this method

```
class ObjectMapper[T] {

  def readValue(x: String, t: Class[T]): T = ???
}

class Reader {
  def read[W: Manifest](x: String): W = {
    val mapper = new ObjectMapper[W]
    mapper.readValue(x, implicitly[Manifest[W]].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[W]])
  }

}
```

May I know why TypeTag doesnt have method runtimeClass

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the `TypeTag` comes from `scala.reflect.runtime.universe`, you can get the class like this:

```
def runtimeClass(tag: TypeTag) = tag.mirror.runtimeClass(tag.tpe)
```

It doesn't have this method because not all `TypeTag`s are from the runtime universe.

Comment: This is absolutely correct. If a TypeTag comes from a macro universe, then the JVM class that it refers to might not have been generated yet.

Comment: @EugeneBurmako - Wouldn't that be be an argument to supply a method that returns `Option[Class[A]]`?