# Scala pattern matching on generic type with TypeTag generates a warning while ClassTag not?

Tags: scala, reflection, compiler-warnings

I have two very similar methods. The only difference is the use of `ClassTag` and `TypeTag`:

```scala
def matchClass[A: ClassTag](v: Any) =
    v match {
        case a: A => "it's A"
        case _ => "not A"
    }

def matchType[A: TypeTag](v: Any) = ... // same code as matchClass
```

A compile warning will show for `matchType`, but not for `matchClass`:
`abstract type pattern A is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure case a: A`

Why is there a warning? why does it show only for `TypeTag` and not `ClassTag`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't see a warning for `classTag` because that check simply works for those:

```
scala> matchClass[Int]("aaa")
res82: String = not A

scala> matchClass[Int](5)
res83: String = it's A
```

And doesn't work for `typeTag`:

```
scala> matchType[Int](5)
res84: String = it's A

scala> matchType[Int]("aaa")
res85: String = it's A
```

The reason is that for pattern matching on classTags (when it's seeing an implicit) compiler generates something like:

```
case a: A if classTag[A].runtimeClass.isInstance(a) => ...
```

There is no way to get `runtimeClass` for `TypeTag`s in general (considering both compile&runtime, see the UPDATE for a specific case allowing to extract it in runtime only), so that's why compiler doesn’t transform them. By default, pattern matching can't match on generic (polymorphic) types because of erasure, so you can see that warning by default:

```
 scala> def matchGeneric[A](v: Any) =
 |     v match {
 |         case a: A => "it's A"
 |         case _ => "not A"
 |     }
<console>:28: warning: abstract type pattern A is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
               case a: A => "it's A"
                       ^
matchGeneric: [A](v: Any)String
```

UPDATE: As @Seth Tisue mentioned [when a tag comes from **run-time universe (only)**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26338549/86485) you can get a runtime class for it (but you gonna have to create a mirror first).

---

Reference:

As per [scaladocs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/index.html#scala.reflect.ClassTag@unapply(x:Any):Option[T]) of `ClassTag` itself:

> The compiler tries to turn unchecked type tests in pattern matches into checked ones by wrapping a `(_: T)` type pattern as `ct(_: T)`, where `ct` is the `ClassTag[T]` instance. Type tests necessary before calling other extractors are treated similarly. `SomeExtractor(...)` is turned into `ct(SomeExtractor(...))` if `T` in `SomeExtractor.unapply(x: T)` is uncheckable, but we have an instance of `ClassTag[T]`.

`TypeTag` scaladocs and language spec itself don't mention any such functionality for `TypeTags`

---

Speculative explanation

*There is no way to know for certain why some features are implemented or not, so any speculation would be opinionated (and out of SO scope, and isn't even related to your question directly, but to answer @Tom's comment). Nevertheless (as of 2.12)...*

This is probably because "ClassTags provide access only to the runtime class of a type" and are part of [scala-library](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.6/) (even though their package is `scala.reflect.`), while TypeTags are a part of a separate (and quite wide-broad) reflection API thus are meant to refer to either compile or run time depending on the `universe` they're in, so writing the additional checks (during synthesis!!) for those would be not just confusing (for users) but also hard for language developers: synthesis itself is in a different ([compiler](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.6/scala-compiler/scala/)) module and [synthesis] doesn't depend on [reflection](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.6/scala-reflect/scala/reflect/) (only scala-library) as pattern matching synthesis is happening on early "patmat" stage. Also, scala spec (12.3.4.2 Variance) mentions usage of ClassTag's for synthetic adjustments of array instantiations which (very speculatively) could mean that ClassTags are more integrated with the "syntax sugar"-features.

Comment: Funny, I didn't actually tested to see if it works with `TypeTag`. I assumed it would work, since `ClassTag` contains a sub-set of the information in `TypeTag` (that is according to the documentation), meaning there's no reason it won't work with `TypeTag` as well.

Comment: re: "There is no way to get `runtimeClass` for `TypeTag`", see http://stackoverflow.com/q/26338549/86485

Comment: Given the fact that we can get `runtimeClass` through `TypeTag`, It looks that this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Tom 1) It directly answers the question itself "Why is the warning?", "why does it show only for TypeTag?" or do u think u can interpret it better than the OP? 2) Idk how many edits I have to make to highlight the fact that it works only in runtime universe, so implementing logic (in the compiler) that checks the universe of the tag isn't just hard (as unlike with classTag - u can't just "add" `if(blabla.runtimeClass==)` and ignore implicit resolution [which is a separate phase] of the universe), but also would confuse developers even more

Comment: @Tom Or you want me to find a deep philosophical meaning to a specific "syntax sugar"-type compiler feature that isn't even mentioned in a language specification?