# Difference between scala's ClassTag and TypeTag

Tags: scala, reflection

According to scala doc，`TypeTag` contains more information than `ClassTag`. It seems to me that `TypeTag` can do more things than `ClassTag`, like bring the type parameter information of compile time to runtime, etc.

However, the following example shows that `ClassTag` can do the job, while the `TypeTag` not. I want to understand why.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag
// def func[T](o: Any): Unit = {
// def func[T : TypeTag](o: Any): Unit = {
def func[T : ClassTag](o: Any): Unit = {
  o match {
    case x: T => println(Some(x))
    case _ => println(None)
  }spark
}
func[Map[Int, Int]](List(1, 2, 3))
```

Only `ClassTag` will lead the pattern matching to `None` (which is the expected behavior), the first two commented lines will come up with `Some` branch.

It seems that `ClassTag` can reflect on object's type on runtime, while `TypeTag` can't. But isn't `TypeTag` a superset of `ClassTag`？ I would like to know the explanation as detailed as possible. Thank you.

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495711/scala-pattern-matching-on-generic-type-with-typetag-generates-a-warning-while-cl) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 9):

this page will help you!
take a look :)

https://medium.com/@sinisalouc/overcoming-type-erasure-in-scala-8f2422070d20

**add more detail, since only link answer is not appropriate...**

ClassTag : runtime information about value, but not good with generic style
TypeTag : runtime information about type

e.g.

```
object Test extends App {

  import scala.reflect.ClassTag
  def func[T : ClassTag](o: Any): Unit = {
    o match {
      case x: T => println(x)
      case _ => println(None)
    }
  }
  func[List[String]](List(1, 2, 3)) // List(1, 2, 3), not None!!! with List[String] type parameter... ClassTag only recognize List scale, not List[T]

  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
  def func2[T](o: T)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): Unit = {
    tag.tpe match {
      case TypeRef(utype, usymbol, args) => println(args.toString)
      case _ => println(None)
    }
  }
  func2(List(1, 2, 3)) // List(Int)
}
```

Comment: To add, ClassTag also returns the underlying Java class if a scala type is an alias to the Java class (e.g. Long/String/etc.)