# Difference between Object and AnyRef in Scala

Tags: scala, types

From [this scheme](https://docs.scala-lang.org/resources/images/tour/unified-types-diagram.svg) in the [Unified typed](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/unified-types.html) article in Scala tour I thought that `AnyRef` and `Object` are full equivalents.

However, when inspecting declarations in Eclipse, I've found some interesting things:

```
object ClassTag {
  …
  val Object  : ClassTag[java.lang.Object] = Manifest.Object
  …
  val AnyRef  : ClassTag[scala.AnyRef]     = Manifest.AnyRef
  …
}

object TypeTag {
  …
  val AnyRef:  TypeTag[scala.AnyRef]     = new PredefTypeTag[scala.AnyRef]     (AnyRefTpe,  _.TypeTag.AnyRef)
  val Object:  TypeTag[java.lang.Object] = new PredefTypeTag[java.lang.Object] (ObjectTpe,  _.TypeTag.Object)
  …
}
```

Some experiments:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

println(ClassTag.AnyRef == ClassTag.Object) //true
def getClassTag[V](v: V)(implicit tag: ClassTag[V]) = tag
println(getClassTag[AnyRef](null)) //Object
println(getClassTag[Object](null)) //Object
println(getClassTag(null.asInstanceOf[AnyRef])) //Object
println(getClassTag(null.asInstanceOf[Object])) //Object
println(getClassTag(new AnyRef())) //Object
println(getClassTag(new Object())) //Object
println
println(TypeTag.AnyRef == TypeTag.Object) //false
def getTypeTag[V](v: V)(implicit tag: TypeTag[V]) = tag
println(getTypeTag[AnyRef](null)) //TypeTag[AnyRef]
println(getTypeTag[Object](null)) //TypeTag[Object]
println(getTypeTag(null.asInstanceOf[AnyRef])) //TypeTag[AnyRef]
println(getTypeTag(null.asInstanceOf[Object])) //TypeTag[Object]
println(getTypeTag(new AnyRef())) //TypeTag[Object]
println(getTypeTag(new Object())) //TypeTag[Object]
println(getTypeTag(new AnyRef().asInstanceOf[AnyRef])) //TypeTag[AnyRef]
println(getTypeTag(new AnyRef().asInstanceOf[Object])) //TypeTag[Object]
println(getTypeTag(new Object().asInstanceOf[AnyRef])) //TypeTag[AnyRef]
println(getTypeTag(new Object().asInstanceOf[Object])) //TypeTag[Object]
println
println(TypeTag.AnyRef.tpe == TypeTag.Object.tpe) //false
def getType[V](v: V)(implicit tag: TypeTag[V]) = tag.tpe
println(getType[AnyRef](null)) //AnyRef
println(getType[Object](null)) //Object
println(getType(null.asInstanceOf[AnyRef])) //AnyRef
println(getType(null.asInstanceOf[Object])) //Object
println(getType(new AnyRef())) //Object
println(getType(new Object())) //Object
println(getType(new AnyRef().asInstanceOf[AnyRef])) //AnyRef
println(getType(new AnyRef().asInstanceOf[Object])) //Object
println(getType(new Object().asInstanceOf[AnyRef])) //AnyRef
println(getType(new Object().asInstanceOf[Object])) //Object
```

So, at least at some levels of type information `Object` and `AnyRef` are somewhat distinguished. What is it done for? Or is it purely a bug?

Comment: `TypeTag` and `ClassTag` just provide two different things. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40202504/difference-between-scalas-classtag-and-typetag and https://medium.com/@sinisalouc/overcoming-type-erasure-in-scala-8f2422070d20

What you are likely seeing with `TypeTag ` is the actual distinction between `AnyRef` and `Object` since that `TypeTag` deals with the types and `AnyRef` is indeed different than `Object` type wise since `AnyRef` is just a `trait` and is indeed different than `AnyRef` https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/2.12.x/src/library-aux/scala

Comment: Note that you don't need `getTypeTag`, you can just write e.g. `implicitly[TypeTag[AnyRef]]` to summon an instance.

Comment: @DanielHinojosa, it's interesting that `AnyRef` is declared as a trait. But I don't think it's really a trait, I think some compiler magic processes such core things in standard library differently. First of all, I believe to [Seth Tissue's opinion](/a/53435873); second, I can do `new AnyRef()`, but not `trait T; new T()`; third, `typeTag.mirror.runtimeClass(typeTag.tpe).isInterface()` returns `false` for `AnyRef` (usually it returns `true` for traits).

Comment: @Sasha That is an interesting catch and I think the README right before would lead to some answers. https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library-aux/README. "Source files under this directory cannot be compiled by normal means. They exist for bootstrapping and documentation purposes." So there is something during scala bootstrapping that takes the traitness of AnyRef and merges it with `java.lang.Object` at runtime (maybe) and yet the `AnyRef` and `Object` for `TypeTags` are distinct.  Now, what is happening at bootstrap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll see similar behavior with any type alias, I don't think there's anything particular to `Object`/`AnyRef` in your examples above.

```
scala 2.12.7> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

scala 2.12.7> class C; type D = C
defined class C
defined type alias D

scala 2.12.7> implicitly[TypeTag[C]]
res0: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[C] = TypeTag[C]

scala 2.12.7> implicitly[TypeTag[D]]
res1: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[D] = TypeTag[D]
```

`C` and `D` are distinct but “equivalent” types. See SLS 3.5, "Relations between types" (https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#relations-between-types)